# Multipart with JSON in spring rest is not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, multipartform-data, fiddler

I am trying to create a method which accepts both multipart/form-data and application/json content type in same request. I am using Spring Rest for creating the same. But the call does not reach the method when I requested from Fiddler. Please help

**Service method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json",consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> addField( @RequestParam int customerId,@RequestParam int teId, 
        @RequestPart("file") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles, @RequestParam("toast") String toast, MultipartHttpServletRequest request){
```

**Fiddler**

Header

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=HereGoes;
```

Body

```
 Content-Type: application/json

 ---------------------------acebdf13572468
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="file1.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

  <@INCLUDE *C:\Users\User\Desktop\file1.pdf*@>
 ---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add correct file name in request body of fiddler. In your method it is @RequestPart("file"). So use "file" in "name" field instead of "fieldNameHere" which is generated by fiddler. Your request body should look like below.

```
 ---------------------------acebdf13572468
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file1.pdf"
 Content-Type: application/pdf

 <@INCLUDE *C:\Users\User\Desktop\file1.pdf*@>
 ---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

Comment: @abghel Thanks for the reply. Yes I have noticed that issue already and tried it with no luck.

Comment: What is the error you get? Can you try calling your service using curl?

Comment: @abghel I finally made it working. It was the problem with the RequestParam I was using. Since it was not mentioned in the URI the service was not called. There was no error in the logs but there was 404 returned. Thanks for the help. marking the answer as accepted since you pointed out a problem.